# Django manage.py syncdb doing nothing when used with sqlite3

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I'm not sure if this is an issue specific to sqlite databases but after adding some properties I executed syncdb successfully but still the the columns were not added to the database and when I try the access the model in admin I get `no such column` error.

Why is this happening and how do I overcome this issue?

Details: Django 1.3, Python 2.6, OSX 10.6, PyCharm.

Comment: Is your model listed in installed_apps in settings.py?  Also, can you post your models.py (or at least one class from it)?  Are you trying to update a currently existing database with new columns?

Comment: First, the *app* (module) is listed in settings.py, not the models (and this is how it is supposed to be donbe). I try to add a new column to an existing table. It's fully because if I add a new model it works.

Comment: syncdb will not add columns to an existing table.  You have to manually add them.  See here: http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/SchemaEvolution

Comment: If my answer gave you a right insight please mark it as the correct one

Answer (score 11, accepted):

sync db doesn't make integrate schema changes once the tables are created. You have to delete the database manually and do syncdb again. See the boxed information in this link

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#syncdb

Answer (score 3):

As always, `syncdb` does not migrate the existing schema.

Answer (score 0):

I think one can find solution here: A nice blog to start with Django:
Getting Started with Django REST Framework (DRF) and AngularJS :
http://engineroom.trackmaven.com/blog/getting-started-drf-angularjs-part-1/